# Links not working to connect pages

Tags: html

I know this is a really dumb question but I've been in this CSS class forever and we've not done much with HTML. All of the projects have only had 1 page to style. Now it's final time and I have to create a functional website from scratch that is CSS heavy. Cool, no problem. However... I've forgotten how to link all the pages together. I know you need the  attribute and I thought I had it all set up yet when I click on a link in m navbar, it tells me the page isn't found. I have to be missing something super simple... Can one of you clear this up for me?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>index</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>

    <body>
      <div id="wrapper">

    <div id="masthead"></div>
          <h1>Blow their minds...Not your wallet!</h1>
</div><!-- end masthead -->

<ul id="mainnav">
    <li><a href="index.htm">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="events.htm">Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.htm">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.htm">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Events page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>events</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>

    <body>
      <div id="wrapper">

    <div id="masthead"></div>
          <h1>Blow their minds...Not your wallet!</h1>
</div>
        <ul id="mainnav">
    <li><a href="index.htm">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="events.htm">Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.htm">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.htm">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
```

About:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>about</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>

    <body>
      <div id="wrapper">

    <div id="masthead"></div>
          <h1>Blow their minds...Not your wallet!</h1>
</div>
        <ul id="mainnav">
    <li><a href="index.htm">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="events.htm">Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.htm">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.htm">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
```

and finally a Contact page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>contact</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>

    <body>
      <div id="wrapper">

    <div id="masthead"></div>
          <h1>Blow their minds...Not your wallet!</h1>
</div>
        <ul id="mainnav">
    <li><a href="index.htm">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="events.htm">Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.htm">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.htm">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: what is your file name?

Comment: is it index.html or index.htm?

Comment: Add a `slash` `/` to the front of href link. Something like `<li><a href="/index.htm">Home</a></li>`.

Comment: Please share your project folder screenshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since you have used only `html` tag for question so assuming you are using only html and not any other scripting language (php..etc) there could be following probelms -

- you haven't changed the extension of your pages to `.html`
- your pages are not on the same location i.e same folder
- your links are like `index.htm`, `events.htm` etc which could be
  `index.html`, `events.html` and so on..

try correcting above and see..

Comment: Okay, I changed everything to HTML, placed it all within the same folder and all the links work EXCEPT the home link. I can navigate to "Events" "About" and "Contact" But when I try to go back to "Home" from any of those pages it tells me that it's not found...

Comment: did you changed the content of all the pages... like index.htm to index.html  on all your pages..

Comment: Blah! I got it... I had it saved as something other than "index" in my folder... lol. See? Stupid mistake. Sorry, it's early and I'm only on my 2nd cup of coffee... thanks everyone!